# User Controls Wrapped inside a panel MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wrappanel

I am new to WPF/Xaml and searched for this issue I am facing but found it tough. Requesting some help on this.

I need to display usercontrols (DATABOUND) (horizontally) inside a panel/listview so that they wrap when the width of listview/panel is met, with a vertical scroll bar autoshown (as in figure).
[image]
so far I have this code.

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="3"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}"                   
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"

                  >



                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Focusable"  Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>-->
            </ListView>
```

I have even tried the below code. Yes, it wraps but no scrollbar appears!

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="3"
              Width="100" Height="200" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}"                   
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"

              >

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                         
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10"></WrapPanel>            
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


        </ItemsControl>
```

Note: I am okay with any control that makes this happens. Not necessarily be a listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap items you need to set `ItemsPanel` to `WrapPanel`, like in second example, but you may need to disable horizontal scrolling on `ListView`:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" .../>
```

also, if you want to use `ItemsControl` then `ScrollViewer` is not part of default `Template`, like for `ListView`, so you'll need to wrap in in `ScrollViewer`

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3">
   <ItemsControl ...>
      <!-- .... -->
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and don't forget to move `Grid.Row="3"` from `ItemsControl` definition to `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Thanks,  <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" .../> works for me

Answer (score 1):

You were close :-)

Put your listview with a view panel that is a wrapanel inside your scrollviewer.

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: All I could do on the phone before I went underground, but you got there, so that's fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Wrap panel so you need to specify the width it supposed to take... since wrappanel is inside a items host control wrap panel itself cannot calculate the width.It will try to take all the width with respective to Orientation (in your case its horizontal)

Here is the sample code with list box as items host... in this code i have binded the wrappanel width to the actual width of the list box so that it will never take more width than the list box and also i disabled the horizontal scrolling which you don't need for horizontal orientation and vertical wrapping

**Note: Make sure to change item template before using following code and it will work with all items hosts like  ListView, ItemsControl...**

```
<ListBox Width="500" Height="500" Name="listbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=listbox}"></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="100" Width="100">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**For ItemsControl**

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="3"
              Width="100" Height="200" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}"                   
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
 Name="listbox"
              >

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=listbox}"></WrapPanel>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="30" Width="30">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
```